# Bootstrap form won't submit with image button

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I have made a form with Bootstrap. There is a image button to submit the form but when I click it, nothing happens.

```
<form name="input" action="index.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">                    
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input name="coins" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quanity" >
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usd" placeholder="USD" >
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="paypal" placeholder="PayPal Address" >
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="image" src="/img/ppbutton.png" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    </div><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this.form.submit like below:

```
<input type="image" onclick="this.form.submit()" src="/img/ppbutton.png" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button needs to be a button/submit and styled with CSS:

```
<style>
div.submitter input {
    /*you will need to adjust your stylesheet so it looks the way you want.*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(/img/ppbutton.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid;
    }
</style>

<!-- REPLACE IN YOUR FORM -->
<div class="submitter"><input type="submit" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" /></div>
```

Comment: This made the button on top of a image, the button didn't work to submit either.

Answer (score 1):

It submits the form but it sends values in the form of  x and y coordinates of the image.

For Example:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
```

For this input DOM object it will send `submit.x=[some integer]` and `submit.y=[some interger]`

This is what I used:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
     <img src="/delete.png" width="20" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it within an html Form worked for me.